Replacing a three-way switch
I'm planning to replace a broken light switch. It is a three-way switch (one simple light controlled from two ends of a room).  I plan to simply replace all the wires - after carefully labeling.  But it occurs to me that it would be smart to verify that it was wired correctly the first time while I have it open.
So, how does one verify that all is correct?  I have a little non contact voltage tester and also a multimeter.
As for the switch, it is probably from the 1960s.  When you flip the switch up or down, it doesn't always work and you can feel that something inside isn't making contact correctly.

Can you upload a picture showing the wires attached to this switch? And also a picture showing the wires attached to the other switch? Without seeing both it is very hard to tell.

Did it break during your ownership (have you previously seen the existing setup work)? If so, it most likely was wired correctly, because when wired incorrectly a 3-way will either not work at all, render the light always-on and/or will trip the circuit when activated. That is to say, the likelihood of having a 3-way wired incorrectly yet still performing as expected is quite low. If you have never seen it function correctly, then some testing would indeed be helpful.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I can later but I haven't started the project yet

@CactusCake it has slowly been falling for a few months now and it definitely predates us.

Can you tell us what slowly failing means?  Possible just a loose connection that just needs tightening(easy) or the switch is wearing out(replacement), or maybe something else.

@crip659 I updated.  Definitely something mechanical with this very old switch

Identifying 3-way wires:

Turn off the circuit breaker.
Use the NCVT to confirm there are no hot wires.
Photograph, label, etc...  One of the 3 terminal screws of the switch should be a different color.
Detach all wires from the switch and separate them.
Turn on the circuit breaker.
Find the live wire using either tester.
Flip the other switch.
Find the live wire using either tester.
Turn off the circuit breaker.

With those wires detached, you should observe that the common wire is either always hot, or it's never hot.  This depends whether the line hot wire was connected to this switch or to the other switch.
The 2 other wires are the travellers.  They will either alternate (if you detached a load from the common terminal) or they will be dead (if you detached the line hot from the common terminal).

Exactly what I was looking for!
